# Remove the last element in an array whose length is less than a number Pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe:

```
columns = ['id', 'text']
vals = [
        (1, 'I am good or'),
        (2, 'You are okey'),
        (3, 'She is fine in')
       ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
+---+--------------+
| id|          text|
+---+--------------+
|  1|  I am good or|
|  2|  You are okey|
|  3|She is fine in|
+---+--------------+
```

I want to remove the last word only if it is less than length 3. I tried to do this, but I don't understand how to impose a condition so that the length check is only for the last token. I want to set a non-fixed length condition.

```
df.withColumn('split_text', F.split(F.col("text")," "))\
  .withColumn("split_text", F.expr("filter(split_text, x -> not(length(x) < 3))"))
```

I expect this result:

```
+---+------------+
| id|        text|
+---+------------+
|  1|  I am good |
|  2|You are okey|
|  3|She is fine |
+---+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.withColumn(
 'split_text', 
 f.split(f.col("text")," "))\
.withColumn(
 "split_text", 
 f.expr("if (length( split_text[size(split_text) - 1])<3, slice( split_text, 1 ,size(split_text) -1 ) ,split_text)")).show()

| id|          text|      split_text|
+---+--------------+----------------+
|  1|  I am good or|   [I, am, good]|
|  2|  You are okey|[You, are, okey]|
|  3|She is fine in| [She, is, fine]|
+---+--------------+----------------+

expr explained in detail:
if (
 length( split_text[size(split_text) - 1]) < 3, #conditional (Does the last item in the array have a length less than 3?
  slice( # true condition
   split_text, # array to splice
   1 , #int - start of splice to keep
   size(split_text) - 1 ) , #int  - end of splice to keep
  split_text #false condition
)
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work if I want to remove words less than length 3 at the end? He removes then the beginning

Comment: sorry I flipped to the logic to less than 3. Try the above